# Unable to Store Cookies despite Successful Sending to Frontend - Express and React Setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, setcookie

I'm encountering an issue while hosting my website on a server. Despite successfully sending cookies to the frontend, I'm unable to store them.

Here's an overview of my setup: I'm using Express for the backend and React for the frontend. Below is a snippet of my code:

index.js

```
async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        await connection.authenticate();
        console.log('Connection to database successful');
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to database:', error);
    }
}
connectToDatabase();
  
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});
  
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("??");
const certificate = fs.readFileSync("??");
const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'https://??'}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

const refreshToken = jwt.sign({ shop_id }, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, {
   expiresIn: "1d",
});

res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
   httpOnly: true,
   maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
   secure: true,
   path: '/',
   sameSite: "none",
   domain: "??",
});

httpsServer.listen(??, () => console.log("Server is running on port ??"));
```

I've ensured the CORS headers are properly set and have tried various configurations, but the cookies are not getting stored in the browser.

Despite extensive research and attempts, the cookies aren't persisting. Any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Most probably, you set the cookie as `secure` but navigate to the site via `http` instead of `https`.